SQL Server 2022 Missing columns on Linked Server query
I have a SQL Server 2019 in a remote data center which I will call ABC, and a local developer server which is running SQL Server 2022 I will call DEF. Earlier today I created 3 new columns on my local SQL Server DEF, then afterwards I created a Linked Server connection on ABC to DEF. When I create a query on the ABC server to reference one of the new columns from the DEF server, it looks like:
SELECT [NewCol] 
FROM [DEF].[DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]

I get an error:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'NewCol'.

I have no problem querying other columns in that table, as long as they are not the ones I created today.
For example:
SELECT * 
FROM [DEF].[DatabaseName].dbo.[Tablename]

This runs successfully. The query result shows me all records in the table, but the new columns are missing.
I have deleted and re-created the Link Server connection multiple times after receiving this error, but that does not fix the problem. Why can I see only older columns in the Linked Server table?

Out of curiosity, have you considered using Polybase instead of Linked Servers here?

The name [LocalHost] is somewhat confusing. In remote server  [LocalHost]  is remote server. On home server [LocalHost] is home server. It seems that you are not accessing the remote server in the requests.

Are you sure you created the new column on the same server and database (and schema) that you are accessing? What do you get with the query SELECT * FROM [LocalHost].[DatabaseName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tablename'? Do you see your new column? Is the spelling and case exactly the same?

Thanks all for the suggestions. To be more clear, I will change the server names in the original question. Also, I am certain that the new fields were added on my local server, and I have created a Linked Server connection on the data center server to my local server multiple times.

@Dai, I have read about Polybase but have not experimented with it yet. I will look into it further. Thanks for the suggestion.

What were your INFORMATION SCHEMA select results? Shot in the dark: Is there any chance you are opening a connection, starting a transaction, applying the schema change, and disconnecting without committing the transaction?

I just ran the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query on the data center server back to my local server. It lists all of the old columns, but not the 3 new ones. This table exists only on my local server, so the query would error if I was using the wrong server or database name. The actual server specification includes the host name, instance name, and port number of the local development server.

I have taken the query out of my code and pasted it into SSMS just to eliminate any potential connection issues. At this point it's just a basic SELECT query like in the original question, no transaction statements. I have also stopped and restarted the SQL instance service on the local server twice, just to make sure everything was cleared.

Is it just these columns? If you (temporarily) add a new table, will it show in in a remote INFORMATION_SCHEMA query? If you add a row, can you see it remotely? If you locally query max(CreateDate) or similar on some table locally, do you get the same remotely? If you take the database offline or stop the SQL server service, does the remote access attempt error out? Just trying to confirm positively that the two ends are accessing the same database.  Another thought: If running SSMS, a Ctrl-Shift-R is sometimes needed to refresh the Intellisense cache. Last idea is to run a trace.

I think you may be on to something. I just added a new table to the DEF database, and then tried to query it from the ABC database. The error message states "The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table." I don't see how it is a permissions issue because I can query other tables in the same database. It seems like there is some kind of update missing that makes all objects available in the footprint of target database. Newer objects are missing from the footprint. I will start researching that.

@MarkF - Once you figure it out, let us know, even if turns out to be one of those "Doh!" moments.

I have faced the similar problem. Some queries to LinkedServer work some don't work. And OPENQUERY helped me:
SELECT [NewCol]
FROM OPENQUERY([DEF], 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Tablename]')


Unfortunately this did not solve the problem for me. The new columns are still missing. I can query the table with * and see all the older columns only.
